# The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: javascript, xhtml, freemarker

```
<table id="header" align="center">
    <#assign PI = primaryId />
    <#if (PI.getIdentified())><table id="header" align="center">
```

I run into the following error any help appreciated,I try to read some other related topics but I can't understand exactly what happen. The error pointed to  <#assign PI = primaryId /> .

[Fatal Error] header.ftl:19:23: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Comment: and where you get this error exactly, what is the code.

Comment: what about now the error points to exactly on the beginning of "<#assign"

Comment: Hi zielu, Thank you in advance. I add the code, Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, you are trying to parse the FTL with an XML parser. Of course, FTL is not well-formed XML (though with the square bracket syntax, like `[#assign ...]` it can be). Maybe you meant to parse the *output* of the template as XML, not the template itself.

Comment: Great,  I add "&lt;" for "<" and &glt; for ">" sign and it works fine thanks.

Comment: Then it's well-formed XML, but those aren't FreeMarker directives anymore in that  form...